# Configuring camera properties in new OCV 2.4.3

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam

I may just be googling wrong, but I cannot find out a way (read function) to change properties of camera in the new Open CV. I need to disable **auto exposure** and **auto gain** of the camera.
Is that even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an old question but I want to add a solution to this.

opencv calls underlying v4l methods to query frames, set/get camera properties etc. And the problem is, the calls are not complete. Also for some reason, the library calls v4l methods instead of v4l2 ones. Similar issue [here](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/setting-exposure-on-linux-CV-CAP-PROP-EXPOSURE-and-v4l-td7584521.html). It is solved through modifying opencv code, it seems.

I also checked if opencv can set a property supported in v4l2 -like "manual exposure", "or exposure auto priority". It couldn't. I played around v4l2 to solve this:

```
#include <libv4l2.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// open capture
int descriptor = v4l2_open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR);

// manual exposure control
v4l2_control c;
c.id = V4L2_CID_EXPOSURE_AUTO;
c.value = V4L2_EXPOSURE_MANUAL;
if(v4l2_ioctl(descriptor, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &c) == 0)
    cout << "success";

// auto priority control
c.id = V4L2_CID_EXPOSURE_AUTO_PRIORITY;
c.value = 0;
if(v4l2_ioctl(descriptor, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &c) == 0)
    cout << "success";
```

You can then work with opencv.

Full list of camera controls are [here](http://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/legacy/video4linux/API/V4L2_API/spec-single/v4l2.html#camera-controls).

Comment: just curious, are those settings persistant ?

Comment: Thanks so much ! I have been searching around for a solution like this for a long time. +1

Comment: Thanks, this really helped! I had been googling for this simple solution for few hours before bumping here.

Answer (score 2):

so, there's your VideoCapture:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
```

now you could try to set or get properties:

```
//may work or not, highly driver/impl specific.
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 0 ); 
double exposure = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE);
```

sometimes you can even acces the drivers config dialog this way:

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_SETTINGS , 1 );
```

those constants are in highgui_c.h, around l 333

Comment: So, if the function returns no errors, but dosn't work, does that mean the operation is not supported on my webcam? Is there some return value than may let me know, that the operation failed?

Comment: it's  probably just not implemented. and sadly, no way of finding out apart from 'worked' or not .  but, since those settings are stored in the driver persistantly in most cases, you could try to use other programs to access your cam(vlc!!) and try to set it there

Comment: I also had the idea of using other applications to configure camera, but I am doing program for company which does not want to use third party (downloaded) software. So my application should have all functions integrated.

Comment: Now, I tested it for multiple cams, it worked for none. Is there some another thing that may be set on camera?

Comment: well, using another program at least will show you ( the dev ), if the driver allows changing this property at all. if that's not the case, the more unlikey you can do it from opencv. in my case, i could set HUE, but not EXPOSURE

Comment: and, ofc, you could bypass opencv and go at the  underlying api, directshow, ffmpeg, or vfl, whatever, but it gets extremely yucky there...  out of ideas, sorry ;(

Comment: Thank you for trying. I searched for some camera manipulation libraries, but the worst problem is not finding them, but getting them to work. I never achieved to make opencv to work, a friend of mine did this for me. So I highly doubt I would be able to `cmake` or install some less-supported library.

Comment: we all start small, so did i :)

Comment: @berak maybe someone should report this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OpenCV API to do this using [VideoCapture::Set()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set).  Here is an example of how to set the exposure manually in Python:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,-4)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here are the notes I have about the exposure time for each frame. Though I believe they are camera specific, they give you a good idea.

```
-1  640 ms
-2  320 ms
-3  160 ms
-4  80 ms
-5  40 ms
-6  20 ms
-7  10 ms
-8  5 ms
-9  2.5 ms
-10 1.25 ms
-11 650 µs
-12 312 µs
-13 150 µs
```

The same function has settings for GAIN and many other values, though I have not tried them.

A bit more discussion at 

[Setting Manual Exposure in OpenCV](http://www.principiaprogramatica.com/2017/06/11/setting-manual-exposure-in-opencv/)